# Does there exist a prime $p$ such that $\left|\frac{\mathrm{ord_{p}}(a)}{\mathrm{ord_{p}}(b)}-c\right|<\gamma$ for some small constant $\gamma$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. Then $\mathrm{ord_{p}}(a)$ is defined as the least positive integer $d$ such that $p\mid a^{d}-1$.

Let $a$ and $b$ be two coprime natural numbers greater than $1$ and $c$ be a  positive real number. Does there exist a prime $p$ such that $\left|\frac{\mathrm{ord_{p}}(a)}{\mathrm{ord_{p}}(b)}-c\right|<\gamma$ for some small constant $\gamma$?

Comment: What do you mean with "almost equal"?

Comment: What do you mean with $\approx$?

Comment: No unless you put in some conditions on $a,b$. For instance if $b=a^2$ or one of $a,b$ is $1$ you certainly can't approximate any number.

Comment: Heuristically yes: if $u/v$ is a rational number which lies in the interval $(c-\gamma, c+\gamma)$, the prime number $p=uvk+1$ satisfies $ord_a(p)=uk, ord_b(p)=vk$  with "probability" $\varphi(uk)\varphi(vk)/(p-1)^2$ which "behaves" like a constant "often enough".

Comment: It hurts eyes reading OP-q. Couldn't you have $\ d_p\ $ instead of  $\ \text{ord}_p\,?$

Comment: I would even prefer still more $\ \delta_p.\ $ This would avoid wrong associations.

Comment: @WlodAA What's wrong with $\mathrm{ord}_{p}$? It's a standard notation.

Comment: @Wojowu, that's the problem, that $\ \text{ord}_p\ $ is standard while OP uses this term in a different way.

Comment: @WlodAA How come? The least positive integer $d$ such $p\mid a^d-1$ is the same as the multiplicative order of $a$ modulo $p$, which is what $\mathrm{ord}_{p}(a)$ normally stands for (whenever defined)

Comment: What about $\ s\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}\ $ such that $\ p^s|a\ $ is true while $\ p^{s+1}|a\ $ is false? Isn't $\ \text{ord}_p(a)\ :=\ s\,?$ (for such s).

Comment: I'd have Fermat honored by notation $\ \Phi_p(a).$

Comment: It seems to be already non-trivial for any fixed value of $a,b$. Can we even do the simplest case $a=2, b=3$?

Comment: @WlodAA $s$ such that $p^s\mid a,p^{s+1}\nmid a$ is the $p$-adic valuation of $a$, usually denoted $v_p(a)$. I have not seen $\mathrm{ord}_p(a)$ used to denote this valuation.

Comment: @Wojowu, according to the most beautiful book ever, "Th. of Alg. Numbers" by E.Artin (Gottingen, Germany, 1959, p.29) we have $\text{order}_p a =\infty\ $ for $\ a=0,\ $ and $\text{order}_p a =\nu\ $ for $\ a=p^\nu\cdot b\ $ where $b$ is relatively prime to $a$.

Comment: BTW, "Th. of A.N." is beautiful hence like every pearl it has a blemish -- the note taker and the translator didn't understand Emil Artin's lectures. Indeed, here and there (not often! -- once or twice) there are funny moments (to me they are funny).

Comment: Orders are negatives of logarithms (base $p$) of valuations. (Am I old fashioned?)